# how to import java extensions in a play framework model?

Tags: java, playframework

Hi I would like to import Play framework Java Exension* into a Play framework Model.
In specific I'd like to have in my model:

```
package models;

// various import
import play.templates.JavaExtensions;

@Entity
public class Product extends Model {
    @PrePersist
    public void save_slug(){
        slug = title.slugify();
    }
}
```

But I'm receiving following error

> The method slugify() is undefined for the type String

What am I doing wrong?

*references:
- http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/javaextensions#aslugifya
- http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play%2Ftemplates%2FJavaExtensions.html

Comment: The default behaviour of JavaExtensions is to make the extensions available within the view. You can use the static methods to in your Java code, but normally it is best practice not to save computable values in your db/model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java extensions are static methods of `JavaExtensions` class, you can use them as follows:

```
slug = JavaExtensions.slugify(title);
```